# How do I view a song's composer on my iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

Is there any way of viewing the composer of a particular song in the Ipod Touch? I know you can sort songs by composer, but what I want to do is while listening to a particular album (classical music), view the composers of the different songs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a small app you can find [here](http://tsbps.com/product/playingsonginfo/)

Don't worry, it's all Japanese. But the app works really fine and reads all (!) ID3 tags of the current song playing.

Since I am listening preferably to classical music, too, I hate iTunes non-existent ability to show all relevant tag information.

Comment: Me too. I want to display all the text from any tag without truncation. This is my number one gripe about the iPod touch and the iPhone.

Comment: I tried this and it is working great. I am using it on an iPhone using the new "Music" App. If I am looking at "New" Albums, the app leaves the composer field blank. However, if I add the album to "My Music" I can then see who the composer is. I guess if I am curious about who wrote the music I can always add the album to "My Music" and then take it right off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in the default 'Music' app which is quite simple and straightforward. The only solution would be to add the composer to the track's title but I suppose you already thought about this one...

Finding another app for paying music but with more options would be another solution. Are you open to having another application for playing music?

Comment: Any example of an app that actually allows this would make this an excellent answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: Browsed for more than one hour on the AppStore. Tried several free apps without any success at the moment. Didn't try to paid one obviously. It doesn't seem to be a feature requested by a lot of people whereas I understand the need in case of classical music. Strange no application is providing it.